# Filter file-visiting buffers in emacs ibuffer

Tags: emacs

I would like to have something as simple as hitting `T` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) in [`buffer-menu`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Several-Buffers.html). It hides all non-file-visiting buffers and only shows file-visiting buffers. I guess in [ibuffer](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode), the way would be a filter which I can activate via some `/` combination?

Answer (score 2):

As of Emacs 26.1 <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> runs `ibuffer-filter-by-visiting-file`:

> Limit current view to buffers that are visiting a file.

The NEWS file says:

> *** New filter commands 'ibuffer-filter-by-basename',
>   'ibuffer-filter-by-file-extension', 'ibuffer-filter-by-directory',
>   'ibuffer-filter-by-starred-name', 'ibuffer-filter-by-modified'
>   and 'ibuffer-filter-by-visiting-file'; bound respectively
>   to '/b', '/.', '//', '/*', '/i' and '/v'.

There are numerous other enhancements to ibuffer in this version, so Emacs 26 users should refer to the NEWS for more.

Emacs 25.x (and 24.x) users can acquire it like so:

```el
(when (version< emacs-version "26")
  (with-eval-after-load "ibuf-ext"
    (define-ibuffer-filter visiting-file
    "Limit current view to buffers that are visiting a file."
      (:description "visiting a file"
            :reader nil)
      (with-current-buffer buf (buffer-file-name))))
  (with-eval-after-load "ibuffer"
    (autoload 'ibuffer-filter-by-visiting-file "ibuf-ext")
    (define-key ibuffer-mode-map (kbd "/ v") 'ibuffer-filter-by-visiting-file)))
```

Comment: This must be new. I do not  see this function in emacs 25.1.1

Comment: You're right, it's new in 26.1 along with a raft of other ibuffer enhancements.

Comment: @aartist you can put that in your init file.